# does redis cluster use consistent hashing

Tags: redis, consistent-hashing

I'm using redis cluster 3.0.1.

I think redis cluster use consistent hashing. The hash slots are similar to virtual nodes in consistent hashing. Cassandra's data distribution is almost the same as redis cluster, and [this article](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeHashing.html) said it's consistent hashing.

But [the redis cluster turorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) said redis cluster does not use consistent hash.

What do I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, virtual nodes is quite simalar with hash slot.

But virtual nodes is not an original concept of consistent hashing, but more like a trick used by Cassandra based on consistent hashing. So it's also ok for redis to say not using consistent hashing.

So, don't bother with phraseology.

Answer (score 0):

Consistent hashing gives a lot of nice properties when it hashes servers into a ring:

1. servers are randomly distributed in the ring, good for balancing load in a cluster
2. add/remove a server only affect its neighbors, minimize data migration

However, I don't think you can control which key goes to which server: i.e. I can't do the following assignment:

```
key 1-99 ==> serverA
key 100 ==> serverB

// I can probably reach the same traffic split, 99:1 
// by given more virtual nodes to serverA, but it won't guarantee
// key 1 and key 99 is served by the same machine
```

This is allowed in redis, redis uses [hash slot](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#redis-cluster-data-sharding), which I believe is an **explicit map from hash value -> severs**. This gives you full control, especially it enables multi-key transaction: i.e.

```
key Alice, key Bob ==> serverA
// move 100$ from Alice's bank account to Bob's in one operation
// no need special technique like 2 phase commit
```

The key -> server mapping is now managed by yourself as opposed to by consistent hashing, the drawback is that there are more work/responsibility for the admins, Redis also provides commends to help you with the management: [`rebalance`](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/2566), `reshard`

Disclaimer: this is my own understanding (here's my [sources](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/hash-slot-resharding-and-rebalancing-redis-cluster)), I wish I can just @redis_dev on stackoverflow and let them proofread my answer